# AngularJS: Add indicator to invalid fields using only CSS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do something that in my head is very simple, but all my attempts to make it happen have failed.

Using `ng-model` and `$setValidity()`, I can make any field valid or invalid and angular will add the 'ng-invalid' class to any invalid fields, which is great.  I'm using bootstrap, which has built-in styles for 'input:invalid', which adds a red border around all invalid elements when those elements are in focus.

My problem is that I would like to add a `***` after every input in my form that is invalid so that the user can quickly see which fields need to be fixed.  I thought I could do that using only CSS by doing the following:

```
input.ng-invalid{
    border: 2px solid red; 
}
input.ng-invalid:after{
    content: '***';
}
```

I have an plunker that demonstrates a simple example of this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7qau7S?p=preview).  The example `<input>` is required, so if you just remove the text from the field, it immediately becomes invalid and gets a big red border.  But it doesn't get the `content: '***';` style.

Do I just not understand how the `:after` selector works in CSS?  Or am I doing something else wrong?  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing `input` in your selector worked for me in your plunker.

**CSS2**

```
.ng-invalid:after {
  content: '***';
}
```

**CSS3**

```
.ng-invalid::after {
  content: '***';
}
```

It does not seem to work on an `input`. It is adding the `***` after the `form` which also has the `ng-invalid` class. See this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/1036025

**EDIT 1**

You could do something like this, but it requires a container tag beside your input:

**html**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="This field is required" ng-model="myVal" required="" class="my-input" />
<span></span>
```

**css**

```
input.ng-invalid + span::after {
  content: '***';
}
```

**EDIT 2**

You could also add dynamically the `span` with a directive, either on the `input` element:

```
app.directive('input', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.after("<span></span>");
    }
  }
});
```

Or on the `required` attribute (I suggest to use `ng-required`):

```
app.directive('required', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.after("<span></span>");
    }
  }
});
```

Doing it that way, in combination with the css rule, you would not have to change anything from your view's html.

Comment: nice.  thanks for all the help.  i'll give all these a options a shot and see which works best.